# Flask wtforms not passing form - UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined

Tags: python, flask-wtforms

Ok my first post so I will attempt to be thorough. I believe based on a few other posts that I have this correct, but I continue to receive the undefined error. I want to load how a SelectMultipleField that I fill with values i've pulled from a DB. The user should be able to select the fields they want to include in the result and pass that back to the system. I've included the definition of the class, the route, the .html, and my helper.

```
    Entered in __init__.py with fields attribute defined globally

class renderselect(Form):
    elements = SelectMultipleField('Elements', choices = fields)

@app.route('//', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def xmlsrcfields():
    try:
        # render the template
        form = renderselect(request.form)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form.elements.choices = fields
            form.elements.process(request.form)
        else:
            #action to be completed for other cases
            gc.collect()

    except Exception as e:
        return(str(e)) code here
```

The .html is

```
        <div class = "container">
            <h4>Convertable Elements</h4>
            <br>
            {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
            <form method=post action="/fields/">
                <dl>
                    {{ render_field(form.elements) }}

                </dl>
                <p><input type=submit value=Convert></p>
            </form>

            {% if error %}
                <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong>{{ error }}</p>
            {% endif %}

        </div>
    </div>
```

The helper is

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
    <dt>{{ field.label }}
    <dd>{{ field(**kwargs) |safe }}</dd>
    {% if field.errors %}
        <ul class=errors>
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Full traceback as requested:

```
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:14.887982 2018] [core:notice] [pid 11376:tid 1996320768] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.357777 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613] ERROR:flask.app:Exception on /dashboard/ [GET], referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.357894 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.357917 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.357938 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]     response = self.full_dispatch_request(), referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.357958 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.357978 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e), referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.357997 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358018 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb), referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358036 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358056 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]     raise value, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358075 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358095 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]     rv = self.dispatch_request(), referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358114 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358134 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args), referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358153 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/__init__.py", line 49, in dashboard, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358173 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]     return render_template('dashboard.html', topic_dict = topic_dict), referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358193 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 135, in render_template, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358213 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]     context, ctx.app), referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358263 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/flask/templating.py", line 117, in _render, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358283 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]     rv = template.render(context), referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358300 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358319 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]     return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True), referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358337 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358356 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb), referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358373 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358391 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]     raise value.with_traceback(tb), referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358408 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/templates/dashboard.html", line 1, in top-level template code, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358426 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]     {% extends "headhome.html" %}, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358443 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/templates/headhome.html", line 138, in top-level template code, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358462 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]     {% block body %}{% endblock%}, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358479 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/templates/dashboard.html", line 28, in block "body", referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358497 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]     {{ render_field(form.elements) }}, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358514 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 430, in getattr, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358532 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613]     return getattr(obj, attribute), referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358555 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613] jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined, referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
[Thu Jul 12 10:45:35.358588 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 11378:tid 1955591216] [client 192.168.1.75:53613] , referer: http://192.168.1.115/login/
```

Comment: Where, and how do you render your page? You receive this error since `form` is not defined in your HTML, meaning you haven't passed it to the render. Since you run `gc.collect()` without any arguments in the case of `GET` I can't see how the `form` object is getting to your render.

Comment: Yes thank you. I sort this this out this morning. Totally noob move because I’m completely new to python. Apologies for not posting previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had totally not accounted for rendering the page. Thank you for the responses, though somebody deleted their posts I still appreciate it.

I simply added a render to the return. Naturally you can’t see a page that is not `rendered`